# Mod_rewrite - url rewriting isn't working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been trying to get the mod_rewrite in my .htaccess file to work for the past few hours but I can't seem to pull it off. The .htaccess files definitely work on my server because I've used them before.

I've tried to rewrite it with [this generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php) and testing it with [this tool](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) as well as on my server.

**URL**

I need to turn

http://someurl.com/news-detail.html?id=10&news=this-is-an-article

into

http://someurl.com/news/10/this-is-an-article

or

http://someurl.com/10/news/this-is-an-article

**Rewrite**

I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/news/([^/]*)$ /news-detail.html?id=$1&news=$2 [L]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /(.*)/news/(.*) news-detail.html?id=$1&news=$2 [L]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule news/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)$ news-detail.html?id=$1&news=$2 [L]
```

and many others.

I hope someone can help me out here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your rules like this in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev/hoig/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /news-detail\.html\?id=([^\s&]+)&news=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/news/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/news/([^/]+)/?$ news-detail.html?id=$1&news=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This will support `/10/news/this-is-an-article` URI structure for pretty URLs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But I can't get it to work with this code, it's giving me a 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: There was a typo, It is fixed now. Try updated code.

Comment: Well, for one, it's not giving me a 500 error. But it's not working either.

Comment: In what it is not working? What is location of this .htaccess? Are there other rules also? And what URL did you enter in your browser?

Comment: I imagine, the slash on the RewriteBase line corresponds with the root folder, right? Well, the url isn't being rewritten. There aren't any other rules, no. And the **URL:** `http://websitename.com/dev/hoig/news-detail.html?id=16&news=new-message`

Comment: What is `/dev/hoig/`? You never told anything about this path earlier? Is your .htaccess in `/dev/hoig/`?

Comment: Yeah sorry, so they are subfolders on my server but both the pages as the .htaccess file (and css, js, ...) are in the 'hoig' folder.

Comment: Ah, thought I tried that variation. Thanks, it's working now, but the css (and other files aren't being loaded). Do I need to update their paths or ...?

Comment: For css/js just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
 **OR else** you can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/dev/hoig/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Comment: Right, the `base` tag. Well it's working now, thanks a lot anubhava ;)

Answer (score 2):

Kindly check/add  RewriteBase in your .htaccess file.
Also check if htaccess is allowed to rewrite or not.
Syntax is below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /flodername/
RewriteRule ^urlinbrowser/(.*)/(.*)$ filename.php?first_param=$1&secondparam=$2 [L]
```